# Alternate list elements float with css

Tags: html, css

I have a page where i list messages that is loaded from a database with ajax.
at the moment it is just stacking the output downwards.

I would like to alternate the list elements from left and right similar to a iOS Message chat.
Anyone who got any tips on this? Cant get my head around this...

Comment: Try float left and right?

Comment: we will need your code (HTML/CSS) to answer and please explain exaclty what you don't manage

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52cYS/ Here is how my code and css looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just float them left and right:

```
ul li:nth-child(even) {float:right;clear:left;}
ul li:nth-child(odd) {float:left;clear:right;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Behe/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child` to style alternate items:

```
ul li:nth-child(even) {text-align:right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W9eSK/